# How to "cut" BarLegend

Tags: legending

I'm trying to use a piece of a BarLegend of a ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot to plot other ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot.

Example:

> - output of data1
>
> [image: LIC]

and

> - output of data2
>
> [image]

But for comparing these plots I would like

> ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[ data2, BarLegend["something"]]

with an output of Bar $\approx$ [image] and the plot inside this interval of colors.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: The subject heading somehow reminds me of [the music of my younger days](https://www.discogs.com/Jim-Croce-You-Dont-Mess-Around-With-Jim-Bad-Bad-Leroy-Brown/release/3117683)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the range syntax of [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) for the [`BarLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarLegend.html) and for the [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html) option of the plot with the [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) option set to `False`.

I use `{0, 100}` as the range.  For a the full range.

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 100}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then for range `{0, 50}` of `{0, 100}`

```
BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 100}}], {0, 50}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any sub-range can be obtain; `{25, 75}`

```
BarLegend[{ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 100}}], {25, 75}}, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.